# Wrapping LinearLayout with ScrollView dynamically with Xamarin (C#)

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, scrollable

Hello I am using Xamarin (C#) and I am trying to develop an Android application, 
I need to make my content scrollable, I know that I can do it by changing XML file to something like

```
<ScrollView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout 
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">
                      <!-- Content here -->
                </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But I need to do it dynamically with C# (and Xamarin). This code generates several Buttons and puts them into linearLayout, but I need to put the linearLayout into scrollView to be able to scroll down and see other buttons.

```
var linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
var scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
int count = 30;
linearLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
....
for (int a = 1; a < count; a++)
                {
        var button = new Button(this);                        
            linearLayout.AddView(Button);
        }
SetContentView(linearLayout);
```

Thanks for response or tips how to do it some other way in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Xamarin installed to try this, but according to the documentation, you should be able to use the same `AddView()` method here, since it is a [method from `ViewGroup`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.ViewGroup.AddView/p/Android.Views.View/) and `ScrollView` inherits `ViewGroup` (`ViewGroup` `->` [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.FrameLayout/) `->` [`ScrollView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ScrollView/)) :

```
scrollView.AddView(linearLayout);
SetContentView(scrollView);
```

Comment: Not working for me, 
'ScrollView' does not contain a definition for 'Content'

Comment: I was referring to `Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView`, but, from your comment, looks like you're using the one from `Android.Widget` namespace. Try the updated answer...

Comment: Thank you, it works now, I am gonna answer the question with the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. In the end it was quite easy to do, I had already tried it before, but when I tried it at first it wasn't working for me, I don't know exactly why. Nevertheless it works fine now.

```
var linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

var scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
scrollView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

scrollView.AddView(linearLayout);

int count = 30;
linearLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
....
for (int a = 1; a < count; a++)
                {
        var button = new Button(this);                        
            linearLayout.AddView(Button);
        }
SetContentView(scrollView);
```